# Passing a type that takes a generic into another type, then passing a generic into that type

Tags: typescript

The question is quite confusing, but it's exactly what I'm trying to do. Consider `MyType`, which takes an optional generic type.

```
type MyType<T extends string = string> = { hello: string };
```

I have a lot of different types that all extend `MyType`, but have slightly different properties. One thing they have in common though is that they all have a `hello` property which is a string, and they all take in an optional string argument.

```
type MyType<T extends string = string> = { hello: T };

type WithFoo<T extends string = string> = { foo: 'bar' } & MyType<T>
type WithFizz<T extends string = string> = { fizz: 'buzz' } & MyType<T>
```

I'd like to have a type called `ApplyWorld` which accepts any of these types, and returns the passed in type with the string literal type of `'world'` passed in.

```
type Apply<T extends MyType> = T<'world'>

// usage would be ex. -> Apply<WithFoo>
// type would be { foo: 'bar', hello: 'world' }
```

Is there any way to achieve this other than doing an extremely long conditional type?

My use case is complex and the result of some bad architecture (not my doing) that I now have to maintain. Hope this makes sense - just trying to see if something like this is possible. The example above in TS Playground of course does not work.

Comment: sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), can you please state the X part of the question?

Comment: @niceman The problem is stated. My attempted solution is next.

Comment: I don't think TypeScript supports higher-order types. If that is your question. See this issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213.

Comment: `Apply` could just be `type Apply<T> = T & MyType<'world'>`. Also did you mean to use `{ hello: T; }` in `MyType`?

Comment: @kelly I'd like to not directly refer to `MyType` in `Apply`, but it's seeming like that's the only way to do it. And yes, I did. Thanks!